# How to display the number of posts per each categories in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to display the number of posts per each category in my WordPress theme. So it should appear like that:

- Cat1 (5)
- Cat2 (3)
- Cat3 (2)

The number is the number of posts, so 5 means 5 articles are in Cat1, etc....

I write the following code:-

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( 'orderby=name & title_li' ); ?>
</ul>
```

So what should I add to display the number of posts per each category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the show_count option:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&title_li=&show_count=1'); ?>
```

There are plenty more options too if you want to customise the output further: [wp_list_categories on Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)